# How re-use HttpClient F#

Tags: http, f#

hello everyone i'm new in f#

i created a starter project with giraffe and then i want to make post calls to another api

and ran into the problem of reusing HttpClient and using sockets more efficiently.

```
let url = "https://someUrl"
let httpClient = new HttpClient ()
let! content = postAsync httpClient url Data
        
let result= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result)
```

How correct is it to make web requests and reuse HttpClient?

Comment: This code is incomplete. `let!` needs to be in a computational expression.  Could you show the complete function(s) and how you re-use the client. Plus where is `result` first bound and where is `content` used?

Comment: Reusing is recommended https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0#instancing

Comment: When you have a question, please ensure that you provide as much relevant information as it is possible. Your code is incomplete, and you do not say about what kind of problems you ran into.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=httpclient+using+wrong
MS's official solution to the problem is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests but it's quite heavyweight, depends on DI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Girafe specifically. In a regular ASP.NET core app you add the `HttpClientFactory` during the startup with.
`service.AddHttpClient()` (*Seems like this should be called AddHttpClientFactory*)

Then inject an instance of `IHttpClientFactory` into a controller as a constructor parameter.

Inside the controller create an `HttpClient` with
`var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient()`

Then configure the client settings and make requests using the client as needed.

The factory will manage the pooling of instances behind the scenes.

Maybe some variation on that can be adapted to Girafe.

**See also**
[Make HTTP requests using IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0)